# BGL bundled edge properties containing vector

Tags: boost

I managed to create my graph using the following bundled properties for vertices and edges:

```
struct vertexproperties
{
    // index
    int id;
    // shortest distance to all other nodes
    std::vector<float> dist_to;
    // shortest distance from all other nodes
    std::vector<float> dist_from;

    // constructors (note: empty version is necessary for graph)
    vertexproperties (int id) : id(id) {}
    vertexproperties () : id() {}
};
```

and

```
struct edgeproperties
{
    // weight
    float weight;
    // resources
    std::vector<float> res;

    // constructors (note: empty version is necessary for graph)
    edgeproperties (float weight, int n_res) : weight(weight), res(n_res, 0) {}
    edgeproperties () : weight(0.0), res() {}
};
```

and I've managed to create my graph satisfactorily using

```
typedef adjacency_list<listS, vecS, directedS, vertexproperties, edgeproperties> graph_t;
```

However, I have two questions: One regarding how to use the vector values as property maps when solving for shortest paths, for example with Dijkstra; and the other regarding the apparent necessity to use empty constructors in the `vertexproperties` and `edgeproperties`:

1. When, inspired by [boost bundled properties documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/graph/doc/bundles.html) I try to use

   ```
    dijkstra_shortest_paths(g, s, weight_map(get(&edgeproperties::res, g)));
   ```

   to solve, I get errors of the form `test.cpp:180:41: error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘edgeproperties::res’`, which don't surprise me as I've just passed a vector, and not just a scalar.

   As I have no real idea to do this, I tried to remedy this using `get(&edgeproperties::res[0], g)` and `get(&edgeproperties::res, g)[0]` and both don't work.

   **The first question is how to do this?**
2. It looks like it is necessary to provide the constructors `vertexproperties () : id() {}` and `edgeproperties () : weight(0.0), res() {}`, which actually don't really make sense, as well as the non-empty ones.

   I hesitate to add them because they should never be used: id can only be 0 for one of the vertices, and has to be different for the others.

   Therefore, I would like to know **whether it is really necessary to provide these empty constructors and/or whether I'm doing something wrong there**.

Comment: Thank you so much, @sehe.

I thought I had looked through all the Stack Overflow answers, of which indeed many were yours, but I realize I should have just gone through them all.

Can I somehow accept your marking of duplicate as an accepted answer?

Comment: Nope, but upvoting works. Cheers :)